# Blank video window problems, infinite picture taking issues, and the program will only run once each time it's opened

Tags: python, opencv, detection

I'm having a few problems with a python program that is meant to detect faces from a video and take a picture whenever a face is detected.

**ONE** Whenever I click 'run module' it will run the program. But if I try to run it after this first time I get an error message and it won't run. To run it again I have to close out of the python program and open it again. The error message is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Morgan\Documents\Image recognition\Face Detection\test.py", line 56, in <module>
runCam()
  File "C:\Users\Morgan\Documents\Image recognition\Face Detection\test.py", line 26, in runCam
if len(detect_faces(image))>=0:
  File "C:\Users\Morgan\Documents\Image recognition\Face Detection\test.py", line 36, in     detect_faces
detected = cv.HaarDetectObjects(image, cascade, storage, 1.1, 3, cv.CV_HAAR_DO_CANNY_PRUNING, (100,100))
error: Non-positive cols or rows
```

I have tried googling this with no luck. If anyone has any info, solution, or ideas on how to fix this I would be greatful.

**TWO** In my original video program, the stream worked perfectly. The video window showed video and detected faces as desired. What I did was add a feature to that program that would take a picture everytime a new face was detected. But when this was added it resulted in a gray video window (basically no video stream). I'm not sure why this is.

This is my original video face detection program WITHOUT THE PICTURE TAKING CAPABILITIES:

```
  import cv2
  import cv2.cv as cv

  HAAR_CASCADE_PATH = "C:\\opencv\\data\\haarcascades\\haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml"
  CAMERA_INDEX = 0

  def detect_faces(image):
 faces = []
 detected = cv.HaarDetectObjects(image, cascade, storage, 1.2, 2, cv.CV_HAAR_DO_CANNY_PRUNING,   (100,100))
 if detected:
    for (x,y,w,h),n in detected:
        faces.append((x,y,w,h))
  return faces

if __name__ == "__main__":
    cv.NamedWindow("Video", cv.CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE)

capture = cv.CaptureFromCAM(CAMERA_INDEX)
storage = cv.CreateMemStorage(0)
cascade = cv.Load(HAAR_CASCADE_PATH)
faces = []

i = 0
c=-1
while(c==-1):
    image = cv.QueryFrame(capture)

    # Only run the Detection algorithm every 5 frames to improve performance
    if i%5==0:
        faces = detect_faces(image)

    for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
        cv.Rectangle(image, (x,y), (x+w,y+h), 255)

    cv.ShowImage("Video", image)
    i += 1
    c=cv.WaitKey(10)
```

And this is with the new feature added:

```
import cv2
import cv2.cv as cv

camera_port = 0

ramp_frames = 1

def operateCamera():

camera = cv2.VideoCapture(camera_port)

def get_image():
     retval, im = camera.read()
     return im

for i in xrange(ramp_frames):
    temp = get_image()
    print("Taking image...")

    camera_capture = get_image()
    cv2.imwrite("c://Users/Morgan/Pictures/Logitech Webcam/color_image.jpeg", camera_capture)

def runCam():
while 1:
    if len(detect_faces(image))>=0:
        operateCamera()
    else:
        print("No faces detected!")

HAAR_CASCADE_PATH = "C:\\opencv\\data\\haarcascades\\haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml"
CAMERA_INDEX = 0

def detect_faces(image):
faces = []
detected = cv.HaarDetectObjects(image, cascade, storage, 1.1, 3, cv.CV_HAAR_DO_CANNY_PRUNING, (100,100))
if detected:
    for (x,y,w,h),n in detected:
        faces.append((x,y,w,h))
    return faces

if __name__ == "__main__":
cv.NamedWindow("Video", cv.CV_WINDOW_NORMAL)

capture = cv.CaptureFromCAM(CAMERA_INDEX)
storage = cv.CreateMemStorage()
cascade = cv.Load(HAAR_CASCADE_PATH)
faces = []

i = 0
c=-1
while(c==-1)
    image = cv.QueryFrame(capture)
    runCam()
    # Only run the Detection algorithm every 5 frames to improve performance
    if i%5==0:
        faces = detect_faces(image)

        for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
            cv.Rectangle(image, (x,y), (x+w,y+h), 255)

        cv.ShowImage("Video", image)
        i += 1
        c=cv.WaitKey(10)
```

**THREE** Because I am able to run the program once successfully, I know that it takes a picture when a face is detected, sadly it continues to take pictures and never stop after it detects the first face. I only want one picture taken. Does anyone know how to solve that?

IN CONCLUSION, I know this is a lot of information and a very large question, but if anyone has any ideas on how to fix the Program will only run once then needs to restart problem, the gray video feed, and/or the take only one picture problem please let me know! Thanks! (Also sorry if my indenting looks a little funny on here....)

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Here, take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/about).  There is way too much in this question.  You need to post a question which (a) only asks one question and (b) is as concise as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is very, very garbled. I'm trying my best to parse it, but you have **many** issues.

**ONE and TWO** I think that error is occurring because you are trying to open the same camera twice. It is hard to tell with the formatting. The gray frame is definitely due to opening the camera twice; the same gray frame appears when you try to open a camera that doesn't exist.

There are some typos in the second code example, such as `while(c==-1)` without a colon. You've got so many indentation problems. I would avoid using the cv bindings. Stick with cv2 if possible.

**THREE** You call `runCam()` every time during the `while(c==-1)` loop. It'll save every single frame of video.

I modified a small bit of code from a small face detector program I was playing with. It uses `cv2.CascadeClassifier()` instead of `cv.HaarDetectObjects()`. Maybe it will help you. You'll need to figure out how to tell one face from another.

```
import cv2

cascade = "C:\\opencv\\data\\haarcascades\\haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml"

scaling_factor = 4
picture_taken = False
frame_name = "Face Tracking"

capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cv2.namedWindow(frame_name)

classifier = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cascade)

while cv2.waitKey(1) == -1:
    success, frame = capture.read()

    downsized_frame_template = (frame.shape[1] / scaling_factor, frame.shape[0] / scaling_factor)
    downsized_frame = cv2.resize(frame, downsized_frame_template)
    possible_faces = classifier.detectMultiScale(downsized_frame)

    if len(possible_faces):
        if not picture_taken:
            cv2.imwrite("c:\\Users\\Morgan\\Pictures\\Logitech Webcam\\color_image.jpeg", camera_capture)
            picture_taken = True
        for face in possible_faces:
            x, y, w, h = [v * scaling_factor for v in face]
            cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (255, 255, 255))

    cv2.imshow(frame_name, frame)
```